# How can I search for a string that someone changed with git?

Tags: git, grep, git-blame

I would like to search for a specific string using `git grep` but I would like to filter the results by using `git blame` to know that the string I'm looking for was changed by a specific person.

I just don't know how can I combine them to get the results I want.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You want to find the current line with that string or the commit that changed that string?

Comment: exactly what git grep does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a little shell script to accomplish this:

```
git rev-list --author=Doe HEAD |
while read rev; do
    if git show -p $rev | grep "PATTERN" >/dev/null; then
        echo $rev
    fi
done
```

This will output the SHA's that are reachable by HEAD that have an author of "Doe" and have "PATTERN" in the commit content's.

Comment: Thank you @Jonathan.Brick I was just wondering if there's any way to do it without a script, I mean isn't there any git command that I can use to accomplish this?

Comment: @SaulOrtega I did some googling and unfortunately I couldn't find one...it would be nice if git-grep had an --author option. But, perhaps you could wrap this command in an alias, called something like "grepAuthor" so you could easily invoke it without having to type out all that?

Comment: Inverting this by starting with `git grep` and piping to `git annotate` with an appropriate `-L` option might work a bit better... maybe.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.

```
author="Some User"
searchstring=string
searchfiles=(file1 file2 file3) # Leave empty for all files.

while IFS= read -rd '' file; read -rd '' nr; read -r line; do
    if git annotate -p -L "$nr,$nr" -- "$file" | grep -q "$author"; then
        printf '%s:%s:%s\n' "$file" "$nr" "$line"
    fi
done < <(git grep -nz "$searchstring" -- "${searchfiles[@]}")
```

Whether this works better/faster than Jonathan.Brink's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34056151/258523) is going to depend on the volume of matches for the line, the size of the history, where the author's commits live in the history, whether the change is in a more recent or less recent commit of the author's, etc.

Uses `git grep -z` to be safe for arbitrary file names and `read -d ''` to read those `NUL`-delimited fields.

Uses `git annotate -L` to limit lines that need annotation.

Output is the original `git grep -n` output but only for the author-matching lines.

Comment: I still can't believe there's not a flag or a command to do this :(

Comment: I can, in the sense that it makes a relatively cheap `grep` operation into a more expensive (and potentially **much** more expensive) annotate operation. That said it would certainly be handy for you in this case. You *might* be able to get away with `git log -S` if the string was added/removed in the revision you care about.